# change text color in spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I want to change a text color in text spinner in dropView. I tried to override the method getDropDownView and change a text color but it doesn't work.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            extendedCursor, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER) {

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,android.view.ViewGroup parent){
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                Context mContext = AddEditLoadActivity.this;
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                // Androids orginal spinner view item
                v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
            }
            // The text view of the spinner list view
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);


            boolean disabled = !isEnabled(position);
            if(disabled){tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}
            else{tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);}

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            extendedCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            return extendedCursor.getLong(extendedCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.DictionaryTable.ITEM_ID));
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` this line in your spinner adapter use default behavior, try using custom layout to change text color.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@color/your_color" />
```

make sure its id will be `@android:id/text1` and don't be changed.

Comment: I add this and my apk now is crash in logs I see : https://paste.ofcode.org/JQVA2vGz44HBJwSyF7q8uc

Answer (score 0):

use own custom layout

1. Create a layout named `spinner_row.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <TextView
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="#316FA2"
           android:textSize="12sp"
           android:gravity="left"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:padding="6dip"
           android:textColor="@color/white" />///you can add your color 
   />
   ```
2. replace `android.R.layout` with `R.layout.spinner_row.xml`